# mysql cannot execute user_id

Tags: php, mysql

Here there is an image of me making my MySQL table, but when im trying to save it, it gets up an error that

> #1089 - Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique prefix keys

[[image: image description][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tLRa.png)

Here you can see how the error looks like in the SQL Editor, the will be a code in bottom of the descriptiong (SQL query CODE)

[image: image description]

```
CREATE TABLE `User_System`.`usersystem` (
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `username` VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL ,
    `password` VARCHAR(1024) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL ,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL ,
    `last_name` VARCHAR(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL ,
    `active` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`(11)))
ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci
COMMENT = 'User login and register';
```

Comment: You just need to remove `(11)` from the primary key definition. It should be `PRIMARY KEY (user_id)`

Comment: Thank you very much! This works! Thumbs up, have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `(11)` from your primary key definitions. the key should contain column names only, not their type or size

Comment: Thank you! I already know from the comments! This was the fastest answer I've ever got, Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 2):

From the error: "the used key part isn't a string". So don't use a prefix key. :)

The size specifier on integers is just a display hint; it's not actually part of the type.